# Share Vagrant VMs dynamic IP with other VMs

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I would like to create multiple VMs at once with Vagrant. The problem is that those VMs have to communicate with each other. I could use static IPs but I would like to know if there's a way to dynamically set the IPs and then share them with the other VMs so that they can communicate with each other.

Here's a little use case to be more specific. I have two servers, a web application server and a web service server. The web application needs the IP of the web service server. Both servers are managed with Vagrant and Chef.

Comment: Are you using Chef-solo or Chef-client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here: either give every VM static IP or teach them to find each other.

1. You can write down static IP in Vagrantfile like [said in documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html).
2. You can use Chef-server and [use search](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_search.html) in your recipes based on some node attribute (or recipe in run-list, which is in fact also an attribute).

Choose either of the two.